# problem between selected s tag default value and chosen value

Tags: jsp, struts2, drop-down-menu

I have a OrganisationName select box in Edit/Add User Page.

```
<s:select key="user.organisationname" name="entity.organisationId" list="organisationList" listKey="organisationId" listValue="organisationName"></s:select>
```

I have two situations for Two Login User Type (System Admin & Organisation Admin).

1)Existing User, OrgnisationName will be displayed accordingly to his/her organisationId.

2)For New User, Login user can select any desired OrganisationName from the select box.

***for System Admin, select box will display all Organisation Name.
but for Organisatoin Admin, select box will display only his related Organisation Name.***

My problem is I use if else to check whether the login user is System Admin or Org Admin.And I disabled the select box if the login user is Org Admin.

The problem starts from this point. When I disabled the select box, I can see the correct OrganisationName. but **When I save the edited user, the organisationId returned from select box always become 0.**

***How can I pass the correct value even I disable the select box?***

Another Question: **Is there any way that to visible = "false" , similar property for select tag?**

Thanks.

Comment: Add tag `jsp` to enable `syntax highlighting`.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `<s:select />` readonly/unchangeable by

```
<s:select

    onfocus="this.defaultIndex = this.selectedIndex;"
    onchange="this.selectedIndex = this.defaultIndex;"
/>
```

**OR**

Enable a `<s:select disabled="true" />` when the form is submit

```
<s:form onsubmit="document.getElementById('sltOrgAdmin').disabled = false">
    <s:select id="sltOrgAdmin" disabled="true" />
</s:form>
```

---

`visible = "false"` equivalent to `visibility: hidden;` in css

```
<s:select cssStyle="visibility: hidden;" />
```

Comment: @Ischin Thanks for the quick reply. your tip is cool. but user can see the organisation Name. If I want to limit the user not to be able to see other organisation names, what can I do ?

Comment: @Ischin, when I set <s:select cssStyle="visibility: hidden;" /> , the select box disappear, but not the title of select box. how can I fix that? thanks.

Comment: You'd need to change the style of the surrounding markup, or, don't display the select box at all and pass in the form values in another way (if you really need to pass them in again). For example, you could render a hidden field if they're not an admin.

Comment: @Ischin, thanks for the great tip. Like you said, I firstly disabled it. and then on form submit , I enabled it again. working well. Thanks you so much. :)

Comment: @Dave `<s:select />` is use to iterate through the `organisationList` to get the `organisationName` of selected `organisation`. But I agree with you, I would use the hidden field too (with Hibernate). **e.g.** `${user.organisation.name}` & `<s:hidden name="user.organisation.id" />`

Comment: @Dave Or with factory method (without Hibernate). e.g. `<s:property value="findOrgNameById(%{user.organisation.id})" />` & `<s:hidden name="user.organisation.id" />`

Comment: Yes, I know what the select tag does.

Comment: @Dave I never doubt about that. :) (As you are the author of this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Apache-Struts-Web-Application-Development/dp/1847193390))